# initializing scope using ng-init is not binding in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi I am trying to bind a value to a directive using '@' which is defined in the ng-init event. but this doesn't comes into my directive and it returns undefined. When does this property actually resolves is it in Compile, link? Also, why is it returning undefined always? What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="demoController" ng-init="init()">
    <h1>Confused directives!!!</h1>
    <my-user userName="{{user.name}}"></my-user>
    <br>
    {{user.name}}
  </body>

</html>

(function(){
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app', []);


    app.controller('demoController', ['$scope', demoController])

    function demoController($scope){
        console.log('Im in the controller');
        $scope.init = function (){
            $scope.user = {
                name: 'Argo'
            }
            console.log('Im in init method of controller')
        }
    }

    app.directive('myUser', myUser);

    function myUser(){
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                userName: '@'
            },
            template: '<div><b>{{userName}} is defined from init method </b></div>',
            link: function(scope, ele, attr){
                console.log('Im in link method of directive');
                console.log('this is loaded' + scope.userName);
                attr.$observe('userName', function(newValue){
                    console.log(newValue);
                })
            }
        }
    }
})();
http://plnkr.co/edit/vAKMNub8HRcphiaMMauR?p=preview
```

Comment: can you setup a plunker

Comment: You should use the attribute name `user-name` and not `userName` as you've done in your HTML. Furthermore, the official documentation states that `ng-init` should only be used in a special case where aliasing is required, so call your initialisation function in your controller instead.